# Array and pointers to structures

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

So I have this structure

```
struct Data {
int id;
string message;
};
```

I am trying to create an array of struct pointers and fill it with values using this

```
Data *stack[10];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    stack[i] = (struct Data*) malloc(sizeof(struct Data));
    stack[i]->id = i;
    stack[i]->message = "message" + i;
}
```

however, I keep getting an error (segmentation fault when debugging) from `stack[i]->message = "message" + i;`
Can anyone please help understand what's causing the error and how to solve it?

Comment: Don't use `malloc`, use `new`.

Comment: `malloc` does not create any object, and therefore it will not call constructor of `std::string message`. Use `new`, or, better yet, do not use pointers at all.

Comment: What do you think `"message" + i` is doing?

Comment: the `"message"` string literal has only 7 characters... When `i` is `8` you are already pointing beyond its null terminator...

Comment: @Yksisarvinen understand now. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the working example. You can use smart pointers for automatic memory management, that is the destructor will be called automatically when reference count goes to zero.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
struct Data {
int id;
string message;
Data()
{
    std::cout<<"default consructor"<<std::endl;
}
~Data()
{
    std::cout<<"destructor "<<std::endl;
}
};
int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; 
   std::shared_ptr<Data> stack[10];
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    
    stack[i] = std::make_shared<Data>();
    stack[i]->id = i;
    stack[i]->message = "message" + std::to_string(i);//make sure to convert the integer to std::string 
    }
    
   //check the value of id for first element in stack
    std::cout<<stack[1]->id<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

You can also use `new` instead of `malloc` but then you will have to call `delete` explicitly. Note the use of `std::to_string()` to convert the integer `i` to string.

Comment: [for some relaxed definition of "working"](https://godbolt.org/z/PKs85oKsh)

Comment: Yeah i have used std::to_string() now. Thanks for pointing it out, though i already spotted the mistake but since the program worked at:  https://wandbox.org/permlink/2spzemigtlBtGECv , i waited for some time to correct it. Thanks for pointing it out.